# Unable to view tomcat website externally

Tags: web, tomcat9

I have a server running tomcat. I can view the website fine on the same lan network but when I try the external IP it doesn't work. I port forwarded 8080, 8009 and 8005 tcp and udp. (I know the ports are forwarded because I used the same rule as my website that uses port 80 which works). The external firewall says that the connection is timing out, meaning the server is not replying. My connector in tomcat is the following:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useIPVHosts="true"
           address="0.0.0.0"               />
```

Do you know why I am not able to see the website on my external IP? It has to be an application issue since port 80 works on my website and i am using the same rule to forward 8080. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is within same Subnet or network ?

Comment: It works within the same network. The server and my computer are on different subnets.

Comment: Most probably some firewall ??

Comment: I disabled windows firewall, and when I check my firewall it shows the packets are being sent but the server is not responding to it.

Comment: Can u ping the IP address ?
if yes  , then try to telnet the port .